# How can I pass a variable to a view, in Codeigniter 3, if it is not in the URL

Tags: codeigniter, codeigniter-3

I am working on a **blog application** in Codeigniter 3.1.8 and Bootstrap 4.

The posts can be filtered by categories. I want to display the number of posts in each category.

[image]

The **categories** table in the database looks like this:

[image]

For this purpose, I have done the flowing:

In the **Posts_model** model I have added the function:

```
public function get_num_rows_by_category($id) 
{ 
    $query = $this->db->get_where('posts', array('cat_id' => $id));
    return $query->num_rows(); 
}
```

In the Categories controller I have added the line

```
$data['number_of_posts_by_category'] = $this->Posts_model->get_num_rows_by_category($id);
```

In the **Sidebar** view:

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
   <a href="<?php echo base_url('/categories/posts/'.$category->id); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
      <span class="text-muted"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
      <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill"><?php echo $number_of_posts_by_category; ?></span>
   </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

The problem with this approach is that the `$id` variable (representing the category id) is no passed via the single post page URL. So there is this **error**:

```
Message:  Undefined variable: number_of_posts_by_category
```

What is a viable alternative.

Comment: post your category table pls - because the number of posts with in a category shouldn't be dependent from your content

Comment: I have just posted an image of the categories table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that this is for display only. I assume as well that you have `Posts_model` and `Categories_model`.

```
class Categories_model extends CI_Model {

    // Method for retrieving categories.
    public function get_all_categories()
    {
        return $this->db
            ->order_by('whatever', 'DESC/ASC') // anything
            ->get('categories')
            ->result();
    }

}
```

Now we go to `Posts_model`:

```
class Posts_model extends CI_Model {
    // Method that count posts in categories.
    public function count_posts_in_category($cat_id)
    {
        return $this->db
            ->where('cat_id', $id)
            ->count_all('posts'); // Or count_all_results (Check please)
    }
}
```

The next thing to do is to use both methods in your controller this way:

```
class Your_controller extends CI_Controller {

    // I assume you loaded all libs and models.
    public function your_method()
    {
        // Get categories first.
        $data['categories'] = $this->categories_model->get_all_categories();

        // Now we add posts count:
        if ($data['categories'])
        {
           foreach ($data['categories'] as &$category) // Notice the "&".
           {
                $category->posts_count = $this->posts_model->count_posts_in_category($category->id);
           }
        }

        // Then load your sidebar and pass $data:
        $this->load->view('your_sidebar', $data);
    }
}
```

The view should be (I copied yours) and please, always use `site_url` for URLs (except for assets, you may use `base_url`):

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
    <a href="<?php echo site_url('/categories/posts/'.$category->id); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
        <span class="text-muted"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
        <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill"><?php echo $category->posts_count; ?></span>
    </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: I will implement your solution as soon as I can. Thanks a lot for the tips too.

Comment: I get the error message `Message:  Undefined property: stdClass::$posts_count` in the view.

Comment: I don't see why you get this error. I must see the code you're using :/

Answer (score 0):

The model where you get all your categories needs to get adapted in order get the Postcount

Categories_model (or however you named it)

```
$query = $this->db
    ->select('c.*, count(p.cat_id) AS cntposts')
    ->from('categories c')
    ->join('posts p', 'c.id = p.cat_id')
    ->group_by('p.cat_id')
    ->get();

return $query->result();
```

your view

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('/categories/posts/'.$category->id); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="text-muted"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill"><?php echo $category->cntposts; ?></span>
  </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

Comment: show your model - and what do you mean with _it does not work_ ? do you get any errors ?

Answer (score 0):

**Hope this will help you :** (do it with the help of CI helper)

*create a `custom_helper.php` and add it to the helper folder and load it via `autoload.php`*

```
$autoload['helper'] = array('custom');
```

In helper create function like this:

```
function get_num_rows_by_category($id)
{
   $ci = & get_instance();
   $count = $ci->Posts_model->count_all_where(['cat_id' => $id]);
   return $count;
}
```

**Note** : *make sure you have loaded your model in autoload.php or in controller*

Add this method to `Posts_model` :

```
public function count_all_where($where)
{
    if ($where)
    {
        $this->db->where($where);
        return $this->db->count_all_results('posts');
    }
}
```

Your view should be like this :

```
<?php foreach ($categories as $category): ?>
  <a href="<?php echo base_url('categories/posts/'.$category->id); ?>" class="list-group-item list-group-item-action">
    <span class="text-muted"><?php echo $category->name; ?></span>
    <span class="badge badge-secondary badge-pill"><?php echo get_num_rows_by_category($category->id) ?></span>
  </a>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```

For more : https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/helpers.html

Comment: have you tried my answer, is it helpful for you or not

Answer (score 0):

First you should function post of your controller you should call your function `get_num_rows_by_category` of your `post_model`